# Idea. Аргументы командной строки Java.

Tags: java, intellij-idea

У меня такая ситуация, в примере к задаче вот такие входные данные

> 25 80
>   9876543210987654321098765432109876543
>   9876543210987654321098765432109876543
>   9876543210987654321098765432109876543

В условии сказано: "На первой строке во входном потоке данных пользователь вводит числа 
N 
и 
M, 
затем 
N 
строк
из 
M 
символов каждая"

Когда я в идее, в параметре programm arguments ввожу пример из условия, то он его меняет вот так:

> 25
>   80
>   9876543210987654321098765432109876543
>   9876543210987654321098765432109876543
>   9876543210987654321098765432109876543

И парсинг строки становится не нужен, а все действия программы сдвигаются на одну строку и работают неправильно. Idea автоматически разбивает первую строку на две, в месте, где стоит пробел. Так вот вопрос, когда мою программу будет проверять компьютер, то в программу придет строка как в условии с пробелом, или уже две строки без пробела?

Надеюсь понятно объяснил проблему.

Comment: Чушь какая-то. program arguments - это же параметры командной строки. Командная строка на строчки не разбивается, а разбивается на отдельные параметры, разделенные пробелом. А idee видимо для удобства показываются каждый в отдельной строке. Очевидно Вам надо не аргументы забивать, а получать ввод пользователя со стандартного _потока_ ввода `System.in` или консоли `System.console()`

Comment: Таким образом через агрументы вы получите отдельно 25 и 80. Чтобы получить один аргумент с пробелом вместо двух без пробелов, обычно такие агрументы заключают в кавычки: "25 80".

Comment: Да, я разобрался, все напутал, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Разделителем аргументов командной строки является пробел. Поскольку два первых числа разделены пробелом, система считает их двумя разными аргументами. Чтобы передать в параметре строку, содержащую пробел, её нужно заключить в кавычки. Таким образом, в данном случае параметры нужно передавать следующим образом:

```
program_name "25 80" 98...
```